# QTP:The whole set like "Menu's -> Tabs->SubTabs " are getting identified as WinObjects

Tags: vbscript, qtp

```
Used RegisterUserFunc 

Function SelectAction(obj,seltext)  
obj.GetTextLocation seltext,l,t,r,b     
obj.click (l+r)/2,(t+b)/2 
End Function 
RegisterUserFunc "WinObject","MenuSelect","SelectAction"
```

This partially resolved my issue,but still facing issue to click on Submenu subtabs due to lack of visibility and application sync issues .

Comment: So what´s your question?

Comment: I used excel ribbion short cuts to resolve this issue .this working smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my tool is developed using excel 2015 ,I used excel ribbion short cuts with the code pasted above .this working smooth.
Eg :ALT,T, E, H (sequential keystrokes)